# Execute python script with file path as argument

Tags: python

I'd like to run python script under windows from command line

this is something like:

```
script_name.py C:\file\path
```

but it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
and highlight 'C' symbol

this script is in C:\Python27\ folder

the code of script downloaded from here https://github.com/faucamp/bootstrap_namespace_prefixer

Comment: How about script_name.py "C:\file\path" ?

Comment: Please add the complete error message

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to type that into the Windows command prompt, not the Python shell.

And you shouldn't put your own code into the Python27 folder.

Comment: I shouldn't because it is not working? or because this is bad style?

Comment: Bad style... That's for libraries that come with Python. If your code gets mixed up in there, it can be a pain to find what's yours later / m,ake sure your code isn't interfering with something else. Create a project folder and store everything in there. You can add Python to the path as mentioned elsewhere so you don't ever need to go to the python directory manually

Answer (score 0):

you can change directory from command prompt `to C:\Python27\` then run python `C:\Python27\folder\scriptname.py` (path to script)

OR

Set environment variable then change directory to `C:\Python27\folder`. `run python scriptname.py`